# scrollbar management of a 'div' with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, scrollviewer

Is there a way to control a scrollbar's life depending on the browser size and the 'div' size at the same time in javascript or jquery. For example, if the 'div' content is overflowing then add scrollbar to div and if the browser is resized to a higher height then remove scrollbar from div, since it's gonna be stretched with the browser:

```
$("#wrapper").height($(window).height() - 215);

var elem = document.getElementById("topPanel");
var errHolder = document.getElementById("error");

if(elem.scrollHeight > elem.clientHeight - errHolder.scrollHeight){
    $(elem).css({
                "overflow-y": "auto",
                "overflow-x": "hidden",
                height: elem.scrollHeight - errHolder.scrollHeight
                });
}

$(window).resize(function(e){
    if(this.clientHeight > 200){
        $(elem).css({
                    "overflow-y": "auto",
                    "overflow-x": "hidden",
                    height: "200px"
                    });
    }
    else {
        $(elem).css({
                "overflow-y": "auto",
                "overflow-x": "hidden",
                height: elem.scrollHeight - errHolder.scrollHeight
                });
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#toolPanel {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

#topPanel {
overflow: auto;
height: 315px;
width: 100%;
background: #069;
border: 1px solid #0CC;
}

#bottomPanel {
position: absolute;
background: #0CC;
border: 1px solid #069;
height: 65px;
width: 100%;
bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="toolPanel">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <div id="topPanel">
        <!-- Content that may overflow -->
    </div>
    <div id="bottomPanel">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is just a head-start but I'm lost... I'm not good with the use of clientHeight/scroll, offset, etc. Please help.

Comment: What is it about your situation that makes the ordinary CSS-controlled "overflow: auto" not work?

Comment: @Shaoz: On resize change the height of the div and keep the style as overflow-y: auto; - just an idea.

Comment: @Pointy: The situation is that, the css-overflow is useful only if the browser isn't resized. But once it resizes, css-overflow becomes useless as everything is stretched. In css to use overflow, a height has to be declared, which is fixed. But browser resizing means that fixed height is useless. The only way to go from fixed to flexible modes, is via programming, unless there's another solution. I just wanna control the scrollbar depending on different resizing and content overflow situations.

Comment: @Q_the_dreadlocked_ninja: I'll try the on resize stuff and let you know...

Comment: No, CSS overflow works whether or not height is explicitly declared, as long as the height of the box is constrained somehow. If you post your HTML and your current CSS it might clear things up.

Comment: @Pointy: My code is a bit complex as I'm not the only one doing the project. So it's bit difficult to retrieve. So it's quite a long code, even if I simplify it. And people tend to avoid long questions, that's why I didn't post it. But I'll try and post it anyway. Check the question again very shortly...

Comment: @Pointy: I have pasted my simplified code, see above. So is what I'm try to achieve: When the 'error' displays, it will push down the 'topPanel', which in turn should trigger the scrollbar to appear on 'topPanel'. Or when the content of 'topPanel' overflows, it will trigger a scrollbar too. Then if the browser is resized the scrollbar should go since there's no need for it anymore. And then if the browser goes back to its original size the scrollbar mode comes back. I hope you get what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with css:

```
overflow-y: auto;
```